# How to solve parameter values from a system of non-linear equations in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm a beginner in matlab. I have three non-linear equations

> ```
> spdratio_fw = ( 1 + afw*(vc_fw)^b);
> spdratio_pa = ( 1 + aps*(vc_pa)^b);
> ind =  (ddhv_fw*( 1 + afw*(vc_fw)^b) - ddhv_pa*( 1 + aps*(vc_pa)^b))/(ddhv_fw + ddhv_pa) ;
> ```

from the above three equations i have to solve for afw, aps and b.

so i wrote the commands and saved in trial.m

```
function F = trial(Y)
afw = Y(1);
aps = Y(2);
b = Y(3);
spdratio_fw = 1.329;
spdratio_pa = 1.168;
ind = 1.312;
vc_fw = 3.2;
vc_pa = 0.76;
ddhv_fw = 20776.82;
ddhv_pa = 2536.54;

fA = spdratio_fw - ( 1 + afw*(vc_fw)^b);
fB = spdratio_pa - ( 1 + aps*(vc_pa)^b);
fC = ind - (ddhv_fw*( 1 + afw*(vc_fw)^b) - ddhv_pa*( 1 + aps*(vc_pa)^b))/(ddhv_fw + ddhv_pa) ;

F = [fA; fB; fC];



end
```

and after that i ran a script

```
afw0 = 0.15; aps0 = 0.15; b0 = 1; 
Y0 = [afw0; aps0; b0];
Y = fsolve(@trial, Y0);
result;
```

but the error i received:

> ??? Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use
>   set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit.  Be aware that
>   exceeding your available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your
>   computer.
>
> Error in ==> optimget
>
> Caused by:
>       Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot
>       continue.

i gave the command :

```
trial
```

and the error is:

```
??? Input argument "Y" is undefined.

Error in ==> trial at 2
afw = Y(1);
```

I have no idea on how to fix it.

Comment: Why and how do you think your problem is different? Show what you've tried, so that we have a starting point to help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function `trail` which calls `fsolve` with input a handle to `trail`. That's an infinite recursion loop. The last three lines should not be part of `trail.m`

Besides `trail` is a function, you cant call it as `trail`, you have to pass the parameter `Y`, for example `trail(Y0)`

Comment: ok according to the suggestions i deleted the last three lines(i edited the code above accordingly. but the same error exists. do i need to change the name "trial"?